# 405 (Method Not Allowed) En Busqueda ajax laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda con AJAX y me dice `405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

No sé queé pueda ser, ya intenté mirando las rutas y no logro dar con el error.

Mi AJAX

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:{
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $('#form').submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post('/getSearch', data, function(search)
            {
                $('#data').html('');
                $.each(search, function (key,val){
                    $('#data').append('<tr>'+
                    '<td> '+val.name+'</td>'+
                    '<td> '+val.address+'</td>'+
                '</tr>');

                });

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Mi Controlador

```
    class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $req)
    {
        $datas= search::all();
        return view ('search', compact ('datas'));
    }


    public function getSearch (Request $req)
    {
        if($req->ajax())
        {
            $find= search::where('name', 'LIKE','%' .$req->search. '%' )->get();
            return response()->json($find);

        }
    }


}
```

Y mis rutas

```
//---------------------------------search-----------
Route::get('/search','SearchController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/getSearch', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');
```

Comment: Estas declarando las rutas con el método `get` pero en el ajax utilizas `post`,  puede utilizar el siguiente  método para indicar múltiples verbos: `Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/ruta', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En primer lugar, debes mirar lo que es [el error HTTP 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response
>   status code indicates that the request method is known by the server
>   but has been disabled and cannot be used.

Es decir,

> El código de respuesta de error HTTP 405 **Método no permitido**,
>   indica que el método de la petición es conocido por el servidor, y que
>   ha sido desactivado o no está configurado y por tanto, no puede ser utilizado.

Por tanto, lo que ocurre es que **en tu servidor no has declarado la funcionalidad para el método POST**.

Es decir, si no me equivoco, tienes que hacer:

```
Route::get('/search','SearchController@index')->name('index');
Route::post('/getSearch', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas declarando las ruta `/getSearch` con el método `get` pero en el `ajax` utilizas `post` para llamarla.

Para permitir múltiples verbos:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/getSearch', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');
```

Sí quiere permitir solo `post`

```
Route::post('/getSearch', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');
```

Sí quiere permitir solo `get`

```
Route::get('/getSearch', 'SearchController@getSearch')->name('post');
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo la petición por `POST` y la ruta está definida con el método `GET`. Cambia el método de la ruta a `POST` `Route::post('...')` o haz la petición via `GET` `$.get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tuve el mismo error en `Laravel 5.6` y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "**{{ route('buscarCedula') }}**",
       data: {cedula: cedula},
       dataType: 'html',

 });
```

fijense que en la ruta URL, indique la ruta especifica con la palabra reservada de laravel route. A esa ruta mando via ajax, el valor cedula la cual es enviada a un controlador. Antes me daba error cuando usaba: **url: "buscarCedula"**.

Lo mismo me paso una vez en el action de un formulario, me salia el mismo error usando:

**action="buscarCedula"**, haciendo referencia al name de una ruta en el web.php

pero si lo colocaba:

```
action="{{ route('buscarCedula') }}"
```

funcionó sin problemas.

Saludos