# Enviar parámetros controlador laravel con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax

Estoy intentando editar registros con laravel por medio de Ajax con un modal. Tengo la ruta creada, el controlador creado y creo que todo lo necesario. Pero cuando intento hacer la modificación, siempre me devuelve un error 419 en el inspector de elementos y no se porqué, ya que la ruta la tengo configurada como "post", en ajax envio por post... Adjunto mi código.

**Ruta**

```
//rutas funcionalidad modales editar
 Route::post('/editarInstalaciones', 'adminController@editarInstalaciones')- 
 >name('editarInstalaciones');
```

**Controlador**
    public function editarInstalaciones(Request $request){
        $id = $request->id;

```
    echo $id;
    echo var_dump($id);

    exit();

    /*$instalaciones = instalaciones::find($id);
    if(is_null($instalaciones)){
        App::abort(404);
    }else{
        $instalaciones->fill($request->all());
        $instalaciones->save();

    return response()->json([
            "mensaje" => "listo",
        ]);
    }*/
}
```

**corregido**

```
public function editarInstalaciones(Request $request){

    $id = $request->input('id-instalacion');
    $nombreI = $request->input('nombre-instalacion');
    $capacidadI = $request->input('capacidad-instalacion');

    $instalaciones = instalaciones::where('id','=',$id)->update(['nombre'=>$nombreI,'capacidad'=>$capacidadI]);
    return response()->Json($instalaciones);    
}
```

**Ajax**

```
//función boton modal instalaciones
    $('#modificarInstalaciones').on('click', function(){
    //serelizamos el formulario
        var serializado = $("#formularioModal").serialize();
        var idInstalacion = $("#idInstalacion").val();
        var nombre = $("#instalacion").val();
        var capacidad = $("#capacidad").val();

        // limpiamos la tabla
        $('#listado tr').remove();

        // función Ajax
        $.ajax({
            //headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': '{{csrf_token()}}'},
            url: "/editarInstalaciones",
            data: {
                "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
                "id":idInstalacion,
                "nombre":nombre,
                "capacidad":capacidad,
                },
            type: "post",
                success:function(data){ 
                    listadoInstalaciones();
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('imposible Modificar');
                }
            });
    });
```

**Corregido**

```
//función boton modal instalaciones
    $('#modificarInstalaciones').on('click', function(){
    //serelizamos el formulario
        var serializado = $("#formularioModal").serialize();
        var idInstalacion = $("#idInstalacion").val();
        var nombre = $("#instalacion").val();
        var capacidad = $("#capacidad").val();

        // limpiamos la tabla
        $('#listado tr').remove();

        let datos = $('#formularioModal').serialize();
        let send = $('#formularioModal').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:send,
            data:datos,

        }).done(function(data){
            listadoInstalaciones();

        }).fail(function(err){

            console.log(err);   
        });     
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Tras hacer un var_dump he visto esto: `49<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/application/app/Http/Controllers/adminController.php:122:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'49'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
</pre>`

por lo que el id está llegando bien.

Tengo que mencionar, que todos los parámetros los recibo perfectamente, así se ve en el inspector de elementos:

**EDIT**
    _token: HpcLw7bIwWpLhe58G7UMAGUcVWOo3v5C0emcnafy
    id: 49
    nombre: Sala+yuhu4
    capacidad: 30

**Error**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/editarInstalaciones
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error 419 (unknown status) en peticion POST con Ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218794/error-419-unknown-status-en-peticion-post-con-ajax)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por la respuesta @Triby. Me devuelve el siguiente error: http://localhost:8000/editarInstalaciones 405 (Method Not Allowed) y recibo esta info: _token: HpcLw7bIwWpLhe58G7UMAGUcVWOo3v5C0emcnafy
serializado: _token=HpcLw7bIwWpLhe58G7UMAGUcVWOo3v5C0emcnafy&id-instalacion=49&nombre-instalacion=Sala%20yuhu3&capacidad-instalacion=30
nombre: Sala yuhu3
capacidad: 30 se supone que estoy recibiendo el token, y los datos modificados...

Comment: Error 405, ahora lee esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133296/405-method-not-allowed-en-busqueda-ajax-laravel

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Triby he actualizado mi código y en mi pregunta. Pero no hay manera, no veo el problema, mi ruta la tengo definida como estoy enviando el formulario, en ajax esta como post...No lo veo

Comment: Revisa lo que estás enviando en data, creo que en vez de solo `nombre,` debería ser algo como `"nombre": nombre,` y no olvides incluir también ID

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @Triby he modificado eso, y he hecho algunas comprobaciones más.. Pero sigue produciendo el mismo error, no se en que estoy fallando, me encuentro bloqueado

Comment: ¿El error 500 lo obtienes ahora con `var_dump()` y `exit`? Resulta extraño, desconozco Laravel, pero normalmente el error no produce otras salidas

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Lo pongo en la pregunta